# update div in for loop

Tags: jquery, loops, updates

I have a for loop that is supposed to update a div with a counter.

The code looks like this:

```
for(var i=0; i < $this.files.length; i++) {
    var update = setInterval(function() {
        $(".counter").html('<p>Processing file ' + (i+1) + ' of ' + $this.files.length + '.</p>')
    },1000);
//do other stuff
}
```

However it does not update.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you're declaring an update variable and that's it?

Comment: did you mean `this` or `$(this)` maybe?

Comment: what is $this.files.length post more code please.

Comment: @Itay: Yes.
@ponciste: Nope. I meant `$this`. As it is there.
@EmilBorconi: Just before the loop `$this = $('#UploadField');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that while looping, you just define `$this.files.length` different intervals that will work every second forever.

Try this instead:

```
var len = $this.files.length;
var i = 0;
var update = setInterval(function() {
    $(".counter").html('<p>Processing file ' + (i+1) + ' of ' + len + '.</p>');
    if (++i == len) clearInterval(update);
},1000);
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h3Zp8/)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your statement "you just define $this.files.length different intervals". The rest of the function works perfectly. It just doesn't update the div.

Comment: Let's say `$this.files.length = 5`. Your code defines 5 different intervals that work every 1000ms. That means 5 different timers working every second. That's not what you wanted

Comment: Sorry for the late accept and upvote. I was pulled off the project for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work, simply because you are looping trough with i VERY quickly and set up several timers which will expire VERY soon after each other, meaning for the human eye only the last value will be visible, therefore you need to make a loop function with timer to achive the desired result something like this:

```
function update_progress(cur, max){
 setTimeout(function() {
  $(".counter").html('<p>Processing file ' + cur + ' of ' +max + '.</p>');
  if (cur<max) {cur++; update_progress(cur,max);}
  },1000);
//do other stuff
}

update_progress(1, $this.files.length);
```

I hope you see the flaw in your process now, and I hope this helps you. 
Emil